# WPF DataGrid wrong display position of invalid borders of cells when over 40 items

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, virtualization

I using a datagrid to show data as a table and virtualization datagrid. When the total of items is least than 40 item, it goes well.
Therefore, when over 40 items and scroll down, the borders of cells are displayed incorrectly. I'm using Dotnet core 3.1.

Please, I have been working on it for 4 days, and still nothing. Thanks very much!

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
          AlternatingRowBackground="White"
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#d4d4d4"
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="#d4d4d4"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"   
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Here is columns markups:

```html
 <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                    Header="Name"
                    Binding="{Binding PropertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellGotFocus}"
                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellLostFocus}"/>
    
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" 
                            Header="Code">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source, Source={vm:ReplaceModeSourceProvider}}"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding ReplaceMode,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                          SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And here is the styles and templates:

```
  <Style x:Key="CellLostFocus" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,4,0,4"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                                            Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"/>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip.StaysOpen" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="CellGotFocus" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,4,0,4"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                                            Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"/>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip.StaysOpen" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
```

I tried following:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization

Comment: Please post your markup as text rather than a picture. Anyone trying to reproduce your issue would have to type in the many property settings you have there.

Comment: It seems more likely your problem is caused by some other styling or templating you've not shown us. Posting a minimal reproduction would make it much more likely you get a good answer.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for feedbacks, i just post my markup and styles

Comment: I have a different piece of advice then.  Virtualising data is almost always a bad idea.  A user has to scroll through that data to find whatever they are looking for.  You should instead filter and or page large datasets so the user doesn't have to spend all day scrolling.

Comment: Possible causes:  The cell got and lost focus if you have handlers doing things.  That might be expensive as rows scroll in and out of the viewport.  Tooltip.staysopen ( I would just not use this). Data virtualisation. General advice I would give is to start simple, prove that works, iterate with small changes.  Then when you see a problem you know it's caused by the small change you just did.

Comment: @Andy I tried, but the issue is still here.

Answer (score 0):

I've already fixed it. This issue was caused by System.ComponentModel.Annotations

I used DataGridTemplateColumn instead of DataGridTextColumn and removed the default validation templated by setting ValidationErrorTemplate to null.
After that, I created a custom templated and used a trigger to handle UI when an error occurred.

Thanks for supporting. Hope it could help you

```html
     <DataGridTemplateColumn 
                    Width="*"
                    Header="Header">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0.5,0.7,0.7,0.7" Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                <TextBlock Name="textBlock" 
                                           Style="{StaticResource CellLostFocus}"
                                           Text="{Binding PropertyName,
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/> 
                            </Border>

                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" SourceName="textBlock" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Red"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding PropertyName,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                            Mode=TwoWay, 
                                            NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                                       Style="{StaticResource CellGotFocus}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                                        <textboxBehavior:TextBoxTakeFocusAction />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```